# show/hide li element recursively based on input slider

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to show/hide an x number of `li`elements based on an input slider. I'm trying to do this with an algorithm that loops through the amount of `li` elements, and then recursively loops through the amount of differences based on the input slider.

This is what I currently have:

```
/*  updateList
*   @param the event elemenet (input range)
*   @param range value, number of words to display
*/
function updateList(el, range) {
    var originalList = el.srcElement.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.getAttribute("data-value");
    var diff = originalList - range;
    var ul = el.srcElement.parentNode.children[1];

    // for amount of differences
    for (var li = originalList; li > -1; li--) {
        for (var y = 0; y < diff; y++) {
            ul.children[li].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/hubifuvuze/edit?js,output). Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code

```
// for amount of differences
for (var li = originalList; li > -1; li--) {
    for (var y = 0; y < diff; y++) {
        ul.children[li].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

to this

```
// for amount of differences
for (var i=0; i<originalList; i++) {
    ul.children[i].style.display = (i<range) ? "":"none";
}
```

Have a look at this [PEN](https://codepen.io/mjwjon/pen/EKLwoZ) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

i just modify two function as bellow

```
function eventListener(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      updateList(e.target, el.value);
  });
}
```

and

```
function updateList(el, range) {
    var ul = el.nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
    var ul_num = ul.getAttribute("data-value");

    for (var i = 0; i < ul_num; i++) {
        ul.children[i].style.display = "block";
        if ( i+1 > range) {
            ul.children[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    };
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o77txgw0/1/)